# using BDP in R for finding SETTLE_DTE (works in excel but not in R)

Tags: r, bloomberg

I need to get the settlement date of forward contracts in R.

I can do it in excel as below:

```
BDP("CAD1M CURNCY","SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATE",TEXT(C2,"YYYYMMDD"))
```

(assume my specific date for which I am trying to find the settlement date on a 1 month forward contract is at cell C2)

this gives me the settlement date for the forward contract above.
So I want to do the same thing in R (I am connected to bloomberg and can get data)

I tried the followings (and many other versions):

```
bdp("CAD1M Curncy",c("SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATE",as.Date("2018-11-15")))
```

but does not work.

Seems like `SETTLE_DT` is not recognized but I do not know how to make it recognized for bdp in R.

Here are the error messages I get

bdh("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT",REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115"),options=NULL)

Error in bdh("CAD1M Curncy", "SETTLE_DT", REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115"), : unused argument (REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115"))

bdh("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATE" = as.Date("20181115"),options=NULL)

Error in bdh("CAD1M Curncy", "SETTLE_DT", REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115"), : unused argument (REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115"))

bdh("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115")",options=NULL)

Error: unexpected numeric constant in "bdh("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115"

bdp("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115")",options=NULL)

Error: unexpected numeric constant in "bdp("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATE = as.Date("20181115"

bdp("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT",as.Date("20181115"),options=NULL)

Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

bdp("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT",as.Date("2018-11-15"),options=NULL)

Error in bdp_Impl(con, securities, fields, options, overrides, verbose, : Request overrides must be named.

bdp("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATe",as.Date("2018-11-15"),options=NULL)

Error in bdp_Impl(con, securities, fields, options, overrides, verbose, : Request overrides must be named.

bdp("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT",c("REFERENCE_DATe"=as.Date("2018-11-15")),options=NULL) SETTLE_DT CAD1M Curncy 2018-12-31

also if I change the date above to "20181115" instead, it will give me

Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

also with so the last one is the only one which gives me some answer but it is basically only giving me the settlement date of the last forward contract (for today) and does not take into account my reference date. In excel the following command works and gives me the right output: =BDP("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT","REFERENCE_DATE","20181115") output: 2018/12/17

Also tried:

bdp("CAD1M Curncy","SETTLE_DT",c("REFERENCE_DATe",as.Date("2018-11-15")),options=NULL)

Error in bdp_Impl(con, securities, fields, options, overrides, verbose, : Request overrides must be named.

Any ideas? 
Thank you guys really appreciate it

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you receive an error? What does it say?

Comment: Thanks Assylias. I put all the errors I got below so you can see all the alternatives.

Comment: please edit your question (edit link just below the question) and add the information instead of using the answer section.

Comment: Have you tried `bdp("CAD1M Curncy", "SETTLE_DT", c("REFERENCE_DATE"="20181115"))`?

Comment: gives me
Error in bdp_Impl(con, securities, fields, options, overrides, verbose,  : 
  Sub-element '(null)' does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I meant: `bdp("CAD1M Curncy", "SETTLE_DT", overrides = c("REFERENCE_DATE"="20181115"))`

Comment: Solved! Wow... thanks buddy. So the Overrides must be used for anything after the second argument in the function?

Comment: Not always but in most cases yes.

Comment: buddy here is another issue maybe you can have some insights for.
I am trying to get the settlement date for daily  data for the last 6000 days. so I am using bdp for each day using your command to get settlement date but it is taking such a long time. It is faster in excel which does not seem right. How can I make it faster? is there a bdh solution for settlement date which gets the reference dates from the result of another bdh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bdp("CAD1M Curncy", "SETTLE_DT", overrides = c("REFERENCE_DATE"="20181115"))

solved the problem.

Thanks Assylias.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different date format between Excel and R, which is a possible cause. I'd suggest to use ...as.Date("20181115") in R, as well. Also, it would be helpful to share the entire error message.

Comment: Thanks Mourad. I put the errors in the question above